# Multiple event handling on the same function on .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events

I was recently testing with some `FileSystemWatcher`s and wonder how the event handling works in .NET. For example, with this code in VB.NET:

```
Dim fsw1, fsw2, fsw3 As New FileSystemWatcher()

Private Sub fsw_Error(sender As Object, e As ErrorEventArgs) _
                                 Handles fsw1.Error, fsw2.Error, fsw3.Error
    Dim iCont As Integer = 1
    Dim fsw As FileSystemWatcher = CType(sender, FileSystemWatcher)

    While Not fsw.EnableRaisingEvents AndAlso iCont < 120
        iCont += 1

        Try
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            txtResultado.Clear()
        Catch
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = False
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

Each time an error occurs on any of the `FileSystemWatcher`s the function is executed. A different thread for the function is generated for each `FileSystemWatcher`? Can they interfere with each other while executing more than one at the same time?

There is maybe a difference between C# and VB.NET in this?

Comment: I don't see any threads here or multiple FileSystemWatchers - so I wonder what you are talking about...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The `FileSystemWatchers` are fsw1, fsw2 and fsw3. Why the downvotes? This question is about multiple executions of the same function with the events. The code is an example.

Comment: `Dim fsw1, fsw2, fsw3 As New FileSystemWatcher()` would be the multiple FileSystemWatchers, @Daniel Hilgarth; and if I follow, the multiple threads would be those that @SysDragon senses may be related to the events raised by the multiple FileSystemWatchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no constraints for which thread calls an event; if you feel like calling an event in another thread, you are free to do so in .NET. To be honest I cannot imagine implementing a FileSystemWatcher without using a separate thread or async IO for the watcher (which calls the event if a change is found), because you don't want the events to interrupt the normal flow of the application.

Events in .NET work with an invocation list which is called when the event is raised. When invoking an event, the invocation list is walked and each method is called, in a single thread. Simple as that.

The functionality is .NET functionality so the same for both C# and VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

You have a Basic missunderstanding of eventhandling. It seems like you assume ALL the triggered Events will be send to the same function - or lets say to the same *instance* of the function.

This is not the case. Everytime you raise an Event, the function fsw_error will be called. It doesn't matter if there are already 10 executions of that function. So *waiting* inside that function until another Event is raised (it Looks like you are trying to do that) does not work.

However, you can encapsule the eventhandler inside a (instantiiated) class and make sure, all raised Event executions work with the same scope of variables. Im not sure, if Events are fired on different threads (dont think so), but if that is the case you Need to take care of synchronizing the Access of course.

```
Private Class MyEventHandlerHolder
   private iCont as Integer = 0;    

   Private Sub fsw_Error(sender As Object, e As ErrorEventArgs) _
                             Handles fsw1.Error, fsw2.Error, fsw3.Error

       iCont += 1

End Sub
```

iCont will now be increased, everytime the filesystem Watcher fires the Error Event.

```
fsw = new FileSystemWatcher()
fsw2 = new FileSystemWatcher()
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
fsw2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myHandler  = new MyEventHandlerHolder();
AddHandler fsw.Onerror, AdressOf myHandler.fsw_error //not sure about the right Event Name in vb
AddHandler fsw2.Onerror, AdressOf myHandler.fsw_error
```

my vb is Long time back. Maybe you can't target a method of an instance as handler. but require a static (or singleton) Handler class instead.

Answer (score 1):

The handler should be called on a thread-pool thread when the FileSystemWatchers raise events.  The events could interfere with each other insofar as lengthy handling of an event raised by one FileSystemWatcher could delay the handling of another event raised by one of the FileSystemWatchers.  To this extent, you could use a dedicated thread in the event handler to do lengthy, blocking work.

There should not be a difference between VB.NET and C#.